# How to write CSV file correctly?

Tags: python, csv

For giving the model and its data stored in db, I want to write it into an csv file. Yet, the first row of my resulted csv file was not in correct order.

**models.py**

```
class BRANCH():
    ID                  =   db.Column(db.String(6), primary_key=True)
    Branch              =   db.Column(db.String(20))
    Status              =   db.Column(db.String(20))
    Curr                =   db.Column(db.String(5))
    Inputter            =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    Createdon           =   db.Column(db.String(20))
    Authorizer          =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    Authorizeon         =   db.Column(db.String(20))
    Description         =   db.Column(db.String(50))
    LocalDescription    =   db.Column(db.String(50))
    BranchManagerName   =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    LocalBranchManagerName = db.Column(db.String(100))
    ContactNumber       =   db.Column(db.String(35))
    Address             =   db.Column(db.String(100))
    LocalAddress        =   db.Column(db.String(100))
    District            =   db.Column(db.String(9))
    Province            =   db.Column(db.String(3))
    ReportLocked        =   db.Column(db.String(1))
    RegisteredDate      =   db.Column(db.String(20))
    PrevMonthAmount     =   db.Column(db.Numeric(25, 9))
    PrevYearAmount      =   db.Column(db.Numeric(25, 9))
```

So, the data store in db is like below:

```
 Branch | Status | Curr | Inputter  |      Createdon      | Authorizer |     Authorizeon     | ID  |       Description       | BranchManagerName | ContactNumber |                                         Address                                         | District | Province | ReportLocked | RegisteredDate | PrevYearAmount | PrevMonthAmount | LocalBranchManagerName | LocalDescription |                                LocalAddress                                 
--------+--------+------+-----------+---------------------+------------+---------------------+-----+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HO     | AUTH   | 9    | MINAL | 2018-09-10 21:48:13 | MORAKOT.V  | 2018-09-10 21:48:13 | HO  | Head Office             | Chariya Sambeth   | N/A           | #3722,  Sihanou Blv, Veal Vonging, 7 Makara, Phnom Penh City.                           |          | 12       | 10000        | 2015-12-16     |    0.000000000 |     0.000000000 | ចរិយាសម្បត្តិ              | ការិយាល័យកណ្តាល     | ផ្ទះលេខ៥៧១ ក្រុមទី.៥ ផ្លូវ៥៧៤ ភូមិក. ឃុំ-សង្កាត់វាលវង់ ក្រុង-ស្រុក-ខណ្ឌ៧មករា ខេត្ត-រាជធានីភ្នំពេញ
 HO     | AUTH   | 6    | MINAL | 2018-09-10 21:49:26 | MORAKOT.V  | 2018-09-10 21:49:26 | KPS | Preah Sihanouk Province | Lipop Heang       | N/A           | Group 1110 Village 1112 Commune 1112 Preah Sihanouk Preah Sihanouk                      |          | 18       | 10000        | 2016-07-28     |    0.000000000 |     0.000000000 | ហៀង លីបផប់               | ខែត្រព្រះសីហនុ       | ក្រុម ១១១០ ភូមិ ០២ សង្កាត់ ១១១២ ខណ្ឌព្រះសីហនុ ខេត្តព្រះសីហនុ
 HO     | AUTH   | 2    | MINAL | 2018-09-10 21:50:58 | MORAKOT.V  | 2018-09-10 21:50:58 | SRP | Siemreap Province       | Vicheka Kong      | NA            | House 222A, Street 222A, Knar Village Chreav Commune Siem Reap City Siem Reap Province. | 1710     | 17       | 10000        | 2017-11-24     |    0.000000000 |     0.000000000 | គង់ វិច្ឆការ              | ខែត្រសៀមរាប       | ផ្ទះលេខ២២២អា,<U+200B>ផ្លូវលេខ<U+200B>២២២អា,<U+200B>ភូមិខ្នារ សង្កាត់ជ្រាវ ក្រុងសៀមរាប ខេត្តសៀមរាប
```

Here my script to write an these data into csv file:

```
from app.Branch.models import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

TableName = 'BRANCH'

Columns = BRANCH.__table__.columns.keys()

def writeCSV(ID):
    f= open("%s.csv"%TableName,"a+")

    obj = BRANCH.query.order_by(BRANCH.ID).filter(BRANCH.ID==ID).first()

    string = ''

    # set body data
    for col in Columns:
        try:
            string = string + "," + getattr(obj,col).encode('utf-8')
        except Exception as e:
            print col
            string = string + "," + str(getattr(obj,col))

    f.write(string[1:]+'\n')

    f.close

string = ''

f= open("%s.csv"%TableName,"w+")
# set header
for col_header in Columns:
    string = string + "," + col_header
f.write(string[1:]+'\n')
f.close

branchObj = BRANCH.query.all()

for item in branchObj:
    writeCSV(item.ID)
```

Yet, the final csv file is fine except the first row like below:

```
Branch  Status  Curr    Inputter    Createdon   Authorizer  Authorizeon ID  Description LocalDescription    BranchManagerName   LocalBranchManagerName  ContactNumber   Address LocalAddress    District    Province    ReportLocked    RegisteredDate  PrevMonthAmount PrevYearAmount              
 City.  <!> ផ្ទះលេខ៥៧១ ក្រុមទី.៥ ផ្លូវ៥៧៤ ភូមិក. ឃុំ-សង្កាត់វាលវង់ ក្រុង-ស្រុក-ខណ្ឌ៧មករា ខេត្ត-រាជធានីភ្នំពេញ       12  10000   2015-12-16  0   0                                                                   
HO  AUTH    6   MORAKOT.V   2018-09-10 21:49:26 MORAKOT.V   2018-09-10 21:49:26 KPS Preah Sihanouk Province ខែត្រព្រះសីហនុ  Lipop Heang ហៀង លីបផប់  N/A Group 1110 Village 1112 Commune 1112 Preah Sihanouk Preah Sihanouk  ក្រុម ១១១០ ភូមិ ០២ សង្កាត់ ១១១២ ខណ្ឌព្រះសីហនុ ខេត្តព្រះសីហនុ        18  10000   2016-07-28  0   0               
HO  AUTH    2   MORAKOT.V   2018-09-10 21:50:58 MORAKOT.V   2018-09-10 21:50:58 SRP Siemreap Province   ខែត្រសៀមរាប Vicheka Kong    គង់ វិច្ឆការ    NA  House 222A   Street 222A     Knar Village Chreav Commune Siem Reap City Siem Reap Province. ផ្ទះលេខ២២២អា    ​ផ្លូវលេខ​២២២អា ​ភូមិខ្នារ សង្កាត់ជ្រាវ ក្រុងសៀមរាប ខេត្តសៀមរាប 1710    17  10000   2017-11-24  0   0
```

The location where data was truncated is marked by `<!>`.

What is wrong? How can I fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like encoding problem. Try to open("%s.csv"%TableName, "w+", encoding="utf-8")

Comment: @ahmetfteke, thanks, got this error ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    f= open("%s.csv"%TableName,"w+",encoding="utf-8")
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function```

Comment: Try changing `"w+"` to `"mode="w+"`. You cannot have keyword arguments after positional arguments in python. Keywords come first.

Comment: @smallpants, thanks for suggestion. for ```open("%s.csv"%TableName, mode="w+",encoding="utf-8")```, I still get the same error, wondering if I mis-spell keyword argument ```encoding``` :)

Comment: @tgikal, sorry, seem like not valid syntax for python string concatenate.

Comment: I'm confused by the % before TableName in `f= open("%s.csv"%TableName,"w+")`, thought that was a modulus math function.

Comment: @tgikal, not a problem, thanks for contribute :)

Comment: @tgikal I think he's attempting to format the %s in the parameter string with the variable TableName. This is the old style of doing it. I don't know if this would work in this case. I believe one still has to use `'{0!s} {0!r}'.format(data)`

Comment: @smallpants the produced file name is BRANCH.csv which is already consistent with “%s.csv”%TableName

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now, was just looking for a reason why the open error would be occurring.

Comment: hi, any finding on this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this locally with a mocked data source.

Looks like you actually have to close the file to make sure it's flushed.

```
f.close()   # instead of f.close
```

You are doing this in 2 places; note that `f.close` returns the *function*, but `f.close()` actually invokes it. One can reproduce the problem deterministically using

```
def writeCSV(ID):

    f= open("%s.csv"%TableName,"a+")

    obj = BRANCH.query.order_by(BRANCH.ID).filter(BRANCH.ID==ID).first()

    string = ''

    # set body data
    for col in Columns:
        try:
            string = string + "," + getattr(obj,col).encode('utf-8')
        except Exception as e:
            print col
            string = string + "," + str(getattr(obj,col))

    f.write(string[1:]+'\n')
    f.close()
    if ID == 0:
        # here we simulate what would happen if the GC decides
        # to release the first open handle at this point
        g.close()

string = ''

g= open("%s.csv"%TableName,"w+")  # note the rename for demonstration purposes
# set header
for col_header in Columns:
    string = string + "," + col_header
g.write(string[1:]+'\n')
g.close

branchObj = BRANCH.query.all()

for item in branchObj:
    writeCSV(item.ID)
```

Without calling `close` explicitly, you are leaving it up to the GC to decide when  files should be closed, which can lead to bugs like this. See http://blog.lerner.co.il/dont-use-python-close-files-answer-depends/

Related note: consider opening the file *once*, and passing `f` into `writeCSV` to be used, instead of opening the file inside `writeCSV`. Furthermore, consider using the `with` syntax:

```
with open("%s.csv"%TableName,"w+") as f:
    writeHeader(f)
    for item in branchObj:
        writeCSV(f, item.id)
```

That  way, you are guaranteed to be using one output stream in a serialized fashion, and `with` closes the file as soon as it exits.

Comment: Very much thanks for this short and simple solution for me, it does work! Just one quick question, why you define `g` as global inside `writeCSV()`? look your final `g` is `g.close`. hehe.. I correct it to `g.close()` :P

Comment: It was just an example to demonstrate what the GC is actually doing when it eventually closes the file, and wasn't meant to be copied into your module

Comment: Thanks for clarify that and your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try the inbuilt CSV module instead.
Here is an example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
```

Importing the [inbuilt CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). You can refer the documentation for tweaking it.

```
sample = [("Branch", "Status" ,"Curr"), ("HO","AUTH"), ("HO","AUTH",9)]
```

A sample input similar to your data. Let's consider the first tuple as the header.

```
csv.register_dialect(
            'test', 'unix', delimiter=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,
            skipinitialspace=True
        )
test_dialect = csv.get_dialect('test')
```

Here we are creating a custom dialect with the name as "test".  We are specifying the delimiter as one space.

Now let's open a file and write the data to it. Opening the file in with clause will automatically take care of closing it. 
Here we are creating a csv.writer object, testwriter, with dialect as our custom test_dialect.  testwriter.writerow() will write an entire row from the tuple with space as delimiter.

```
filename = "test.csv"
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            testwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, test_dialect)
            for datas in sample:
                testwriter.writerow(datas)
```

The test.csv file will be as follows,

```
"Branch" "Status" "Curr"
"HO" "AUTH"
"HO" "AUTH" 9
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, turple sample which is static data mixing column name and data. In reality, the query object in sqlalchemy will not be that unless we do something to format it in that way, and as input is another table beside BRANCH, column name will not be the same. To be less complex with that, I prefer answer from sample code in question section, and any added code that will fix my first row problem. Thanks